# Diccionario a Archivo csv (Python)

Tags: python, csv

mi problema es que tengo un archivo csv el cual paso a un diccionario. Al momento en que quiero pasar dicho diccionario a un nuevo archivo csv, la informacion se escribe pero dejando una fila en blanco, es decir:

En vez de estar asi:

---

'ejemplo 1': 'hola', 'ejemplo 2': 'hola2...
'ejemplo 3': 'hola', 'ejemplo 3': 'hola3...

---

está así:

---

'ejemplo 1': 'hola', 'ejemplo 2': 'hola2...

'ejemplo 1': 'hola', 'ejemplo 2': 'hola2...

---

me interesa borrar esa linea en blanco, el codigo que uso para la parte de escritura es:

```
    with open('datos_biblioteca.csv','a') as f:
        w = csv.writer(f)
        w.writerows(dic_escritura.items())
```

gracias.

Comment: Hola Sebastian! Tal vez esto te pueda ayudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746908/why-does-csv-file-contain-a-blank-line-in-between-each-data-line-when-outputting

Comment: Tal vez algún valor  contenga un salto de línea? prueba salvar los datos de esta forma: `w.writerows([(e[0],e[1].strip()) for e in dic_escritura.items()])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede probar ingresando linea a linea con un `For`

```
with open('datos_biblioteca.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:  si esta en python 2 en python 3 use 'w'
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for key, value in dic_escritura.items():
        w.writerow([key, value])
```

Python 2
    `with open('datos_biblioteca.csv', 'wb') as f: # use 'wb'`

Python 3
    `with open('datos_biblioteca.csv', 'w', newline='') as f: # use 'w' y newline = ''`

Comment: Hola, sigue apareciendo el problema del espacio.

Comment: El modo de lectura con el que se abre el archivo influye como lo carga después el método `writerow`. actualice mi respuesta con posibles opciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Hola otra opción que puedes utilizar es pandas,puedes revisar su documentación:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('path_to_file')
data_dict = df.to_dict()
# haz algo con el diccionario
df.to_csv('salida.csv')
```